# How come print(workbook.sheetnames) is not working using openpyxl here?

Tags: pycharm, openpyxl

I'm trying some simple Excel work using python and openpyxl. When I run the following code, nothing happens.  I can't figure out why.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def main():
    workbook = load_workbook("FracFocusRegistry_22.xlsx")
    print(workbook.sheetnames)
```

All I get is "Process finished with exit code 0"

I'm using Pycharm and Python 3 (I think 3.8 is defaulting in Pycharm).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function after definition:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def main():
    workbook = load_workbook("FracFocusRegistry_22.xlsx")
    print(workbook.sheetnames)
# Calling the function
main()
```